# bzrlib version doesn't match the bzr program on OSX

Tags: python, version-control, bazaar

Anytime I run bzr commands on OSX I get the following error message:

```
bzr: WARNING: bzrlib version doesn't match the bzr program.
This may indicate an installation problem.
bzrlib is version 2.5.1 from /usr/local/Cellar/bazaar/2.5.1/libexec/bzrlib
bzr is version 2.6.0 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bzr-2.6b2-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/bzr
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the installation got screwed up. If I viewed the bzr script, the version wasn't 5.1.

```
brew uninstall bzr
brew install bzr
```

Uninstalling and reinstalling fixed my issue.